# Has self.column = value to update been deprecated in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I was just trying to use

```
self.name = 'Tom'
```

inside my user model but the column does not get updated.

Using

```
self.update_column(:name, 'Tom')
```

and

```
update_column(:name, 'Tom')
```

works.

Has the first way of changing value been deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.name = 'Tom'
```

Calls the setter method `name=` that ActiveRecord generates from your columns. This just updates the object in memory and marks the attribute as changed so when you call `.save` or `.save!` the changes are persisted to the database.

> Has the first way of changing value been deprecated?

No. You just completely misunderstood what it does. Using the setters has never automatically caused a database update. That would be really unexpected behavior.

`self.update_column(:name, 'Tom')` and `update_column(:name, 'Tom')` are actually the exact same thing. The first just has an explicit recipient while the later is implicit. But in both cases the recipient is `self`. Like its big brother the `#update` method this creates a UPDATE sql query.

Answer (score 3):

`self` is an object, when you do `self.name = 'Tom'`, it just sets the new value in attribute at object level, but to save it in the database, you need to call `save` method on `self` after setting the value.

```
self.name = 'Tom'
self.save!
```

Give it a try!